# SQL subquery and group by produces rows with same values

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, subquery

Currently, I have a query that works fine:

```sql
SELECT teamID, yearID, AVG(HBP) as avgHBP FROM Batting \
GROUP BY teamID, yearID \
ORDER BY avgHBP DESC \
LIMIT 5;
```

RESULT:

```
| teamID | yearID | avgHBP |
|--------|--------|--------|
| BLN    | 1898   | 6.67   |
| BL3    | 1891   | 6.16   |
| BLN    | 1897   | 5.75   |
| BLN    | 1896   | 5.45   |
| BLN    | 1895   | 5.30   |
```

However, when I try to add a subquery (for no other reason than to try learning subqueries),
I get this:

```sql
SELECT teamID, (select yearID from Batting) as yearID2, AVG(HBP) as avgHBP FROM Batting \
GROUP BY teamID, yearID2 \
ORDER BY avgHBP DESC \
LIMIT 5;
```

RESULT:

```
| teamID | yearID | avgHBP |
|--------|--------|--------|
| BLN    | 1871   | 4.44   |
| CL5    | 1871   | 3.93   |
| BL3    | 1871   | 3.86   |
| BFP    | 1871   | 3.69   |
| TL2    | 1871   | 3.55   |
```

where only the first year (1871) is considered for all columns.

Is this because the subquery is applied after the `group by`? If I wanted to add a subquery, what would be the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery:

```
select yearID from Batting
```

returns more than 1 rows (actually it returns as many rows as there are in the table `Batting`) and in any other rdbms, this query:

```
SELECT teamID, (select yearID from Batting) as yearID2, AVG(HBP) as avgHBP 
FROM Batting 
GROUP BY teamID, yearID2
```

is invalid.

But SQLite allows it and returns just 1 row, **which is undefined**.

In short your query is invalid SQL, although it does not throw an error (in SQLite only).

The results that you get by are the same as if you executed:

```
SELECT teamID, AVG(HBP) as avgHBP 
FROM Batting 
GROUP BY teamID
```

with 1 extra column which is the undefined returned `yearID` of the subquery.

For your question:

> If I wanted to add a subquery, what would be the proper way to do it?

the answer is that there is no general rule on *how to add a subquery*.
It depends on the requirement.
For example if you used this subquery:

```
select max(yearID) from Batting
```

which returns only 1 row, then you would have a valid query.

Comment: Scritly speaking, this query is wrong in almost all rdbms exept SQLite and MySql, because according to ANSII SQL, in GROUP BY query all expression in SELECT clause must be also listed in GROUP BY clause.if thea are not aggregate functions

Comment: @krokodilko the result of the subquery is aliased as `yearID2` and it is used in the GROUP BY clause. So this is not the problem here.